# Grails: How to remove any and all HTML tags from a String

Tags: regex, grails, replace

What is a simple, fast and reliable way to remove any and all HTML tags from a text string in Grails?

Answer (score 5):

This first removes any comments (which might contain tags) and then any tags:

```
text = text.replaceAll(/<!--.*?-->/, '').replaceAll(/<.*?>/, '')
```

(via http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Strip-html-tags-tp1316579p1316580.html)

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to use library `Jsoup`. Add to dependency:

```
compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.1'
```

And then use it wherever you want. Simply delete all tags, of course, you can configure parsing. The simplest way to delete is:

```
Jsoup.parse(html).text()
```

Answer (score 0):

I generally do this by regular expression. If tags are missing below just add them:

```
def stripHTMLTags { content ->
  def regex = /<\/?(?i:script|embed|object|frameset|frame|iframe|meta|link|style|a|img|br|p|span|div|hr)(.|\n)*?>/
  content.replaceAll(regex, '')
}
```

---

Source: http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Strip-html-tags-td1316579.html#a1316586

Comment: I'm rather looking for a solution to remove ALL HTML tags. Since the standard surely will be expanded by further tags in the future, having to list them all is not an option as that will need manual amendment.